# Создание объекта, принадлежащего нескольким связям разом

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, нужно чтобы моя модель `Comment` хранила `account_id` который будет получать из `form_for [@account, @account.comments.build]` т.е. из конкретного аккаунта, и `user_id` который будет получать из `current_user.id`  (devise).

Подскажите какую связь поставить и как настроить форму и контроллер чтобы объект Comment сохранял 2 параметра: `user_id` и `account_id`. Аккаунт это товар, а пользователь это модель для регистрации пользоватетей(покупателей). И каждому залогиненому пользователю нужно добавить возможность комментирования аккаунта(товара).

Comment: Почему связь именно полиморфная? У вас комментарии будут использовать еще где-то, помимо комментирования аккаунта?

Comment: @cheops я хочу отображать емайл комментатора используя данные девайс аккаунта который был залогинен во время создания коммента, а account_id нужен для корректного отображения комментов для кажного аккаунта.

Comment: Из праздного любопытства: как у вас связаны аккаунт и пользователь? Какова причина их разделения?

Comment: @D-side аккаунт и пользователь у меня пока не связаны. Аккаунт это товар, а пользователь это модель для регистрации пользоватетей(покупателей). И каждому залогиненому пользователю нужно добавить возможность комментирования аккаунта(товара).

Comment: @Escobar добавьте это в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Вам это и не нужно.

В форме можно эти поля не указывать вовсе.

`user_id` там не нужен потому, что сервер в момент создания может его установить сам из `current_user`, в форме комментария его присутствие не нужно. Подумайте: что будет, если пользователь через DevTools (или аналог) поправит разметку и укажет в `user_id` другое значение? Или вы намерены дополнительно проверять пользователя на честность дополнительным кодом? А не легче ли просто не задавать браузеру вопроса, если знаете ответ заранее?

Когда создаёте комментарий, накладывайте на него скоуп `current_user.comments`, и соответствующее поле в создаваемом комментарии появится автоматически.

```
@comments.merge(current_user.comments).create(comment_params)
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                      |                             |
#                  наложение                 strong parameters
```

---

`account_id`... зависит. Может и нужен, а может и нет. **По-хорошему — не должен бы,** но это требует небольшой детали... которая у вас, кажется, уже реализована?

Судя по вашему объявлению `form_for`, у вас есть ресурс `comments`, вложенный в `accounts`:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :comments
end
```

...тогда URL создания комментария у вас принимает вид `/accounts/{N}/comments`. А значит, аккаунт, на который оставляется комментарий, вы тоже знаете без явного указания прямо в форме (эта информация записывается в action-атрибут формы, адрес, на который форма делает запрос).

И в итоге алгоритм создания нового комментария будет примерно таким:

```
@account = Account.find(params[:account_id])

@account.
  comments.
  merge(current_user.comments).
  create(comment_params)
```

...добавить обработку ошибок и авторизацию по вкусу.

...а что вы при этом делаете в `new`, совершенно неважно. Хоть `Comment.new`. Это важно только если вы хотите какие-то поля спрятать именно в форме.

Comment: да реализована. Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @Escobar вы разобрались? Если да, было бы неплохо увидеть на ответе галку, мол, "объяснение исчерпывающее, проблема решена". Спасибо!

Comment: да спасибо, разобрался, извините забыл поставить.